# How to display only USA states as a select drop-down in custom phtml in Magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, collection, custom

I want to display only USA states as a select drop-down in custom phtml in Magento2.2.5?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in your block class

```
<?php
    ...

    private $directoryData;

    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Directory\Block\Data $directoryData
        ...
    ) {
        ...
        $this->directoryData = $directoryData;
        ...
    }

    public function getStates()
    {
        return $this->directoryData->getRegionHtmlSelect();
    }
}
```

Add following code in your PHTML file

```
<?php

echo $block->getStates();
```

**Extra Notes:**

You can use following code to get the complete data.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$states = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory')
        ->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('country_id','US');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($states->getData());
```

after get dropdown list

```
<select>
<?php foreach ($states as $_state):?>
  <option value="<?php echo $_state->getCode();?>"><?php echo $_state->getName();?></option>
  <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```